# TinyMCE, save_callback and onSaveContent

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, tinymce, save

I'm using the tinyMCE editor with some custom plugins.
The problem I have is when I save the content, I would like do some work before sending the HTML to the server.
I know there is two functions to catch save event.
The save_callback(id, html, body) permit directly to modify the html.
I can't modify content (the DOM or whatever else) in the onSaveContent.

```
save_callback: function (id, html, body) {
    // do the work on html
    return html;
},
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.onSaveContent.add(function (ed, o) {
        //I can't modify
    });
},
```

Also the save_callback is called multiple times (2 or 4) for each save action.

I succeed to modify the HTML in the save_callback, but the function is re-call with the original paramater, and I don't want to do the work a second time because a webservice is called inside.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
save_callback: function (id, html, body) {
    // do the work on html
    return html;
},
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.onSaveContent.add(function (ed, o) {
        o.content = mynewcontent; // here you can modify the content
    });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example if you want to update the editor content using DOM operations rather than string.

```
setup: function (ed) {
    ed.onSaveContent.add(function (ed, o) {
       var images = ed.dom.select("img");
       ed.dom.setAttrib(images, "height", "55")
       o.content = editor.getContent();
    });
},
```